# 10 speed chain on 11 speed cassette

Tags: chain, cassette, drivetrain

Recently I installed an 11 speed cassette and shift levers on my road bike (105 R7000), but I kept the 10 speed chain that I have.

It sort of works fine but on the third cog on the back the chain hops and skids even if I fine tune with a barrel adjuster.

[image]

Is it because a 10 speed chain is not compatible with an 11 speed cassette?

Should I buy an 11 speed chain?

Comment: ok I installed 11 speed chain and it works fine

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain#Width

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each greater "speed generation" of chain is narrower than the last, which is measured in the length of the pins. If you run a wider chain than matches the cassette, it will tend to ride up on the shifting ramps and be otherwise impossible to adjust cleanly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In addition to the points Nathan makes about 10/11 speed compatibility, a new chain should really be installed with a new cassette in any case.

Comment: Thanks, I bought an 11 speed chain today.I will install it in the evening and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as only 0.5 mm is all the chain clearance needs to be out by and no matter how much you adjust you'll not be able to get sweet gear change hope this is helpful

Comment: yes thanks, i installed 11 speed chain and problem solved.i read in some forums that 10 speed chain will work fine with 11 speed cassette but that is not true.

Comment: FWIW, generally the other way works just fine. i.e. you can use an 11 speed chain on a 10 speed cassette. When you are mixing components from different manufacturers this can sometimes help with quieting a noisy drivetrain.